# R shiny RenderDT format specific cell in table output

Tags: r, matrix, shiny

I am trying to format a SPECIFIC cell in a R shiny dashboard data table (using renderDT).

In the UI I use the following line of code:

```
DTOutput('dt_vols')
```

I also include this line in the UI as I dont want to display column names (not sure if that is relevant to the problem)

```
tags$head(tags$style(type = "text/css", "#dt_vols th {display:none;}")),
```

In the server code, I first create the following reactive 2x2 matrix (called dt_vols) - I've simplified the matrix in the example

```
dt_vols <- reactive({

    mtx_vols <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)

    return(mtx_vols)

  })
```

Then I render the DT table as follows:

```
  output$dt_vols = renderDT(

    dt_vols(), options = list(pageLength = 4, dom = 't', autoWidth = FALSE), rownames= FALSE,   
    formatStyle(dt_vols(), columns = 1, border = '1px solid #ddd')

  )
```

It works until I add the formatstyle line. I am not sure how to get this line right and to get it pointing a specific cell (for example row1, column2). It seems to have a problem with the column argument. If i run the below I get the following error:

```
Warning: Error in : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`formatStyle` expects a table object created from `datatable()` as input - you passed a matrix, which results in the error.

Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(DTOutput('dt_vols'),
                tags$head(tags$style(type = "text/css", "#dt_vols th {display:none;}")))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dt_vols <- reactive({
    mtx_vols <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)

    return(mtx_vols)

  })

  output$dt_vols = renderDT({
    myTable <- datatable(dt_vols(),
                         options = list(pageLength = 4, dom = 't', autoWidth = FALSE),
                         rownames = FALSE
    )

    formatStyle(myTable, columns = 1, border = '10px solid #ddd')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you very much, that has solved the problem and works in my code. I have a follow up question. Is it possible to then format the background colour to green of only the cell with the value 3 (first row, second column) and then the background colour of the cell with value 2 (row 2, column 1) to red?

Comment: Dont worry - i have figured it out using style intervals `backgroundColor = styleInterval(lst_vals, lst_colors)` Where the lst_vals was set to a list of the values I wanted to highlight and lst_colors the appropriate color
`