# Bold the first line of a table in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, formatting

I am using the renderTable function, and I'm trying to bold only the first line of an output table in my shiny app.
I have tried to use HTML tags, but the app only prints the tags instead of turning the text bold:

```
output$variableValues <- renderTable({
  pred_probabilities_with_names[1, 1] <- paste0("<b>", pred_probabilities_with_names[1, 1], "</b>")
  pred_probabilities_with_names
}, rownames = FALSE)
```

Another try:

```
output$variableValues <- renderTable({
  # Add HTML tags to highlight the first row
  pred_probabilities_with_names <- pred_probabilities_with_names %>%
    mutate(Class = ifelse(row_number() == 1, HTML(paste0("<b>", Class, "</b>")), Class))
  pred_probabilities_with_names
}, rownames = FALSE)
```

I have also tried to use the DT package, as suggested in [R shiny RenderDT format specific cell in table output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62083271/r-shiny-renderdt-format-specific-cell-in-table-output?rq=3) , with no success:

```
pred_probabilities_with_names$Class[1] <- paste0("<b>", pred_probabilities_with_names$Class[1], "</b>")

output$variableValues <- renderDataTable({
  datatable(pred_probabilities_with_names, options = list(dom = 't'), escape = FALSE)
})
```

Is there a way to do it inside the renderTable function of should I use another method?

Comment: Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69758008/dt-table-shiny-r-formatstyle) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using `renderTable` (without using `DT`):

```
library(shiny)

df[] <- lapply(iris, as.character)
df[1, ] <- lapply(df[1, ], function(x)
    paste0("<b>", x, "</b>"))

ui = fluidPage(fluidRow(column(12,
                               tableOutput('table'))))

server = function(input, output) {
    output$table <- renderTable({
        df
    }, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Using `DT`, one option is to use the `formatStyle` function as discussed in the question which is linked in the comments. If you want to edit the `HTML` as suggested by your question, you can do it like this.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

df[] <- lapply(iris, as.character)
df[1, ] <- lapply(df[1, ], function(x)
    paste0("<b>", x, "</b>"))

ui = fluidPage(fluidRow(column(12,
                               DTOutput('table'))))

server = function(input, output) {
    output$table <- renderDT({
        DT::datatable(df, escape = FALSE)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]